# Calling a service from an External JAR in Android

Tags: android, service, jar, external, manifest

I am trying to call an Android service which is stored in an external JAR file into my android application. When I import the JAR in, everything works fine except the service. If I manually copy the service file into the package and give it a new name, it works, but not when calling the same service by the name it's stored as in the JAR. I have included the package path as well when calling the service. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ashwin I am also trying to do the same... My jar in in android frameworks and I want to access this jar from settings application. I am not understanding how can i link the jar into settings application. Can you please help me in this

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add the service declaration into your manifest even if it is contained in an external jar.

example:

```
<service android:name="com.whatever.something.SomeService"/>
```