# Binding to a service which is in a jar file

Tags: android, binding, android-service

I am having a jar file which contains some service classes. The jar's are placed in  frameworks of Android. I want to bind to that service in an application. Currently I am using this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(IMyAidl.class.getName());
 boolean returnvalue = mContxt.bindService(intent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
 System.out.println("Binding to service in jar are not " + returnvalue);
```

When I am using the above code I couldn't bind at all. Every time `false` is the returned value. I am not understanding why it is returning false.

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: What build script are you using?

Comment: is the service added in manifest?

Comment: @nandeesh: When I am adding service in the manifest file I am getting "Class Not Found Exception"

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700546/calling-a-service-from-an-external-jar-in-android) . did you add fully qualified class name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a build issue. Unpack the apk, and check whether the class your trying to bind to is present in the.dex file

Comment: @Zvi: how can i open a dex file?

Comment: Use dex2jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode

Comment: @Zvi: Can you please provide some code snippet so that i will check with mine.... I am not still understanding the issue...

Comment: Did you try to look at the dex file - were the .class files included there?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable problem you have is that your build script is not configured well. You should have a pre-build step that copies the class files to the directory that converts them into dex format.

Another common mistake that I've seen is forgetting to include the service declaration in the manifest file if the application. If that doesn't work please include more details about the app.

Comment: The way I have done is: Placed the services which are present in the jar files in manifest file of application. But i didnt understand how link will be provided between my application and jar?? Should I configure by some how?

Comment: Have you looked at [this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Comment: Yes I have looked but I am not porting my application in android source code... If I am writing through eclipse it is working but i need to write the application such that it is built in one\