# Declaring an external service in the manifest

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, linphone

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Calling a service from an External JAR in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700546/calling-a-service-from-an-external-jar-in-android)

I am using Eclipse and I got a service which is defined in an external jar. The jar is in the Android Private Libraries in the project's folder.

The answer to the above question said I should define the service in the manifest even if its from an external Jar. My question is how to define something from an external jar in the manifest? I'm used to define a path from the project's src folder which is then simply the package hirerchy. What is the path I should define when the service is defined in the private libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare any imported service or Activity being used by the app in the manifest. To refer them use the full qualifying package name, example if my imported jar/aar library package is : com.example.jar and there is a service in myPackage, called myService, the service would be defined like :

```
 <service
        android:name="com.example.jar.myPackage.myService"
        ...
        ... />
```

Comment: but is it the same for an external jar which is inside the private libraries and not in the src folder?

Comment: If you want to try answering this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693917/resource-not-found-exception-when-trying-to-start-an-external-service