# Resource not found exception when trying to start an external service

Tags: android, linphone

I am using the Linphone library to create some VOIP app. The library is an external jar in the private libraries section in Eclipse.

I'm trying to use the `ChatStorage` class to handle chat messages which is a part of the library.

When trying to start the service I get the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.linphone.LinphoneService: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a003b
```

The problem is that like I said, I'm working with an external jar. From logcat I could see that the problem was caused because of line 137 in the service `onCreate` method and only online I could find the source code of the service in this link:

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/blob/master/src/org/linphone/LinphoneService.java

There I could see that line 137 is:

```
LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().enableLogCollection(!(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.disable_every_log)));
```

What can I do when we're talking about an external jar? Can I somehow edit its content and add this bool resource if its not there?

Comment: Where are you getting the JAR from? This does not seem to be distributed as a JAR, at least on that GitHub repo.

Comment: @CommonsWare from here:  http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads

Comment: Hmmm... they really should be distributing this as an AAR, with resources bundled in. I have no idea how you would fix this, other than by recompiling from source.

Comment: I see no reason for this to be deleted then reposted immediately.